# How to execute shell command with double quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to run this command in Excel using VBA.

"C:\Program Files\GRAPHISOFT\ARCHICAD 25\LP_XMLConverter.exe" l2x -img "C:\temp\gsm\interfaceImages" "C:\temp\gsm" "C:\temp\xml"

I have tested it and it works ok if I manually copy and paste directly into the command line. However when I run it from VBA it doesn't work. I have double-quoted (also tried """ instead of Chr(34) ) but not sure what I am doing wrong? My code is as follows. Note I get the variables from a field within Excel.

```
pathLPXML = Range("Converter!pathLPXML").Value
pathInterfaceImage = Range("Converter!pathInterfaceImage").Value
pathGSM = Range("Converter!pathGSM").Value
pathXML = Range("Converter!pathXML").Value

fullShellString = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & pathLPXML & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " l2x -img " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & pathInterfaceImage & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & pathGSM & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & pathXML & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & fullShellString, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Use `Chr(34)` one time not twice like `Chr(34) & pathLPXML & Chr(34) & " l2x -img "....`

Comment: After trying with one Chr(34) either side of the paths I get this error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: The double chr$(34) will likely be required if the path contains a space as in the case of 'Program Files'

Comment: Actually you got me on the right path. I needed single Chr(34) either side of each path and 1 extra Chr(34) at start and finish of full line.

Answer (score 0):

```
pathLPXML = "pathLPXML"
pathInterfaceImage = "pathInterfaceImage"
pathGSM = "pathGSM"
pathXML = "pathXML"

fullShellString = "cmd.exe /S /K " & Chr(34) & pathLPXML & Chr(34) & " l2x -img " & Chr(34) & pathInterfaceImage & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & pathGSM & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & pathXML & Chr(34)
Debug.Print fullShellString
'output> cmd.exe /S /K "pathLPXML" l2x -img "pathInterfaceImage" "pathGSM" "pathXML"
'Call Shell(fullShellString, vbNormalFocus)
```